# Magento 2 - Store View redirects to main domain

Tags: magento2, store-view

I am running magento 2 in a VM on apache2.

I created a new store view for another language of our shop.

Main domain: `company.com`

Storeview subdomain: `de.company.com`

#### Problem:

If I go to "http://de.company.com" then I get redirected to `http://company.com`.

---

I deleted all cookies and flushed the magento cache.

Comment: Check magento secure and unsecure are set to `de.company.com` for De store

Comment: Yes, they are .

Answer (score 0):

1)Go to Admin CMS Configuration->General->Web->Url Options and store settings like followings:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1)app/etc/frontend/events.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="force_storecode_redirect" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ForceStorecodeRedirectObserver" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2)Observer/ForceStorecodeRedirectObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ForceStorecodeRedirectObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $url;
    /** @var string $defaultStorecode */
    protected $defaultStorecode = 'es';
    /** @var array $storeCodes - array of existing storecodes*/
    protected $storeCodes = [];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
       $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->url = $url;
       $this->storeCodes = array_keys($this->storeManager->getStores(false, true));
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
         $urlParts = parse_url($this->url->getCurrentUrl());
         $path = $urlParts['path'];

         // get storecode from URL
         $urlCode = trim(substr($path, 0, 4), '/');

         // If path does not already contain an existing storecode
         if (!in_array($urlCode, $this->storeCodes)) {
             $path = ltrim($path, '/');
             if ($path == 'en') {
                 $path = '';
             }

             // Redirect to URL including storecode
             header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
             header("Location: " . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . $path);
             exit();
       }
    }
}
```